# Dilemma related to function call's increment of SP

Tags: pointers, operating-system, stack, mips, function-calls

> In case of push during function call, why the stack pointer moves to a
>   smaller value by subtracting 4 times the number of registers to be
>   pushed on the stack?

I got this while reading [Understanding the stack](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html)

Comment: Because, in the actual memory representation, the stack grows from bottom(larger address) to top(smaller address). It has been designed opposite to the growing of heap.

Comment: Please be more specific: don't you understand why a subtraction is performed, why **4** times the number of registers is subtracted, or what?

Comment: @cad I understand that but why 4 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same page, it is clearly mentioned about the memory layout of stack :-

> It's useful to think of the following aspects of a stack.
>
> **stack bottom** The largest valid address of a stack. When a stack is initialized, the stack pointer points to the stack bottom.
>
> **stack limit** The smallest valid address of a stack. If the stack pointer gets smaller than this, then there's a stack overflow (this
>   should not be confused with overflow from math operations).
>
> Other sections of memory are used for the program and for the heap
>   (the section of memory used for dynamic memory allocation).

And, talking about the PUSH operation, subtracting 4 times the number of registers to be pushed on the stack is needed because ***in MIPS architecture, addresses of sequential words differ by 4.*** And, the registers are 32 bits(4 bytes) for MIPS I instruction set architecture (ISA) and II ISA.

For our stack of 4-byte (full word) data, adding an item means subtracting four from **`$sp`** and storing the item in that address.

Here is what that looks like in code. Say that the value to push on the stack is in register **`$t0`**:

```
# PUSH the item in $t0:
subu $sp,$sp,4      #   point to the place for the new item,
sw   $t0,($sp)      #   store the contents of $t0 as the new top.
```

And, so, you can push one or more registers, by setting the stack pointer to a smaller value (usually by subtracting 4 times the number of registers to be pushed on the stack) and copying the registers to the stack.